ipa-replica-install: port 389 in use?
Trying to create a replica to existing (working) freeipa setup.
Following instructions from here.
Client is installed. Host freeipa2 is added to ipa-servers group.
[root@freeipa2 ~]# ipa-replica-install
Your system may be partly configured.
Run /usr/sbin/ipa-server-install --uninstall to clean up.

IPA requires ports 389 and 636 for the Directory Server.
These are currently in use:
    389

The ipa-replica-install command failed. See /var/log/ipareplica-install.log for more 
information

slapd is running at that port. I'd stop it but Im guessing its needed for freeipa server to function. Maybe not?
[root@freeipa2 ~]# netstat -tlpn | grep 389
tcp6       0      0 :::389                  :::*                    LISTEN      854/ns-slapd  

All systems are rocky9.
[root@freeipa2 ~]# rpm -qa | grep ipa
ipa-common-4.12.2-1.el9_5.2.noarch
ipa-client-common-4.12.2-1.el9_5.2.noarch
ipa-server-common-4.12.2-1.el9_5.2.noarch
python3-ipalib-4.12.2-1.el9_5.2.noarch
python3-ipaclient-4.12.2-1.el9_5.2.noarch
python3-ipaserver-4.12.2-1.el9_5.2.noarch
ipa-client-4.12.2-1.el9_5.2.x86_64
ipa-server-4.12.2-1.el9_5.2.x86_64
libipa_hbac-2.9.5-4.el9_5.4.x86_64
ipa-healthcheck-core-0.16-4.el9.noarch
python3-libipa_hbac-2.9.5-4.el9_5.4.x86_64
sssd-ipa-2.9.5-4.el9_5.4.x86_64
ipa-selinux-4.12.2-1.el9_5.2.noarch

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Im pretty sure it gets started when freeipa server is installed. It isn't running on any of other hosts in the network.

ns-slapd is installed by 389-ds-base which is a dependency of ipa-server. Again I ask, was there a previous installation that didn't complete? Regardless, have you run ipa-server-install --uninstall and tried again?
